# How can I manually update Joomla core files without overwriting third-party extensions?

Tags: joomla, updates

When you install Joomla extensions, they may put files into the Components, Modules, Plugins, Media, Images, and possibly other directories. Also, they may save configuration information in some or all of these directories.

In other words, Joomla does not have a clean separation of Core, Third Party, and Local files.  This makes it impossible to manually overwrite a Joomla installation, because you don't want to stomp on any of these files. (Coming from Drupal, this is craaazy-not-best-practice!)

Is there a way to manually update JUST the Joomla core files?

Is there a way to manually update JUST the 3rd-Party extension files? (Yeah, they might be all over the place!)

I'm presently cleaning up a bunch of sites infected with a base64_decode hack. Mixing core files with 3rd-Party with configuration, makes it very difficult to clean things up.

Comment: What are you talking about? YOu just unzip over the installation, third party extensions won't be touched. I'd really just read the instructions, Joomla is tightly organized to keep the core separate from extensions.

Comment: Umm... If I look in my Joomla install, in the following folders: /administrator/components, /components, /modules, /plugins, even /plugins/system I notice a number directories belonging to various extensions that I have installed. So, I would say Joomla core modules are intermixed extensively with third-party modules.

Comment: No, they really are not, each component is in a separate folder in the components directory and updating Joomla files will never touch your extension files and vice versa.   Unzip does not delete any files that it is not overwriting directly nor does FTP.  You have to think of this as just like building a library out of a set of packages, updating one does not impact the others anymore than when you do the same thing via composer. I'm not going to be mean and say you are looking for problems because it seems too easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the process of installing extension in Joomla. Each type of extension is separated as it should be to make life **easier**, not harder. Core files are not to be touched in any way, shape or form, so it simply does not matter of core components are in the same directory as 3rd party component (same goes for modules and plugins).

As for you question regarding manually updating core Joomla files, you can simply :

1. download a copy of the same Joomla version you're using from the official site,
2. remove the configuration.php file and "installation" folder from the zip
3. Upload the zip to the root of your site and extract.

This will replace all core files.

To update 3rd party extensions, all you have to do is download the extension from the developer's site and install it again. You do **not** have to uninstall them first.

The hacked sites you are cleaning up were most likely hacked due to the owner or webmaster not keeping Joomla itself and it's extension update to date.

You see, not that hard :)

Hope everything works out.

Comment: I understand. Unzip doesn't clobber the directories. However, I wanted to overwrite all the directories in order to make sure the vampire, hacked files got the silver bullet. I'm used to Drupal where the system directories are not shared with any 3rd party extensions at all.